# How does .Net DI figure out the correct scope to use?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I know how scoped dependencies are used in ASP.Net but I was wondering how the dependency injection actually figures out the scope when a service is requested?

Is the scope related to a persistent http connection?

Comment: It doesn't. The application or in the case of ASP.NET Core, middleware, explicitly create scopes. In MVC/Web API a new scope is created for each request

Comment: Why are you asking? It may matter, if you create your own middleware classes. If you do, they're essentially singletons unless they implement the IMiddleware interface

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET, the [lifetime of scoped dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#service-lifetimes) is the duration of a single request i.e. a scope dependency will remain "alive" until the server has responded to a given client request.

Answer (score 1):

The DI middleware itself doesn't try to guess the scope. ASP.NET Core middleware explicitly creates a new scope when needed.

- In ASP.NET Core MVC, Web API, Razor Pages and Blazor WASM, that scope is the client request. I think the relevant source is in the [RequestServicesFeature](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/d9b3951b8c4d9cc23738f25471ffdec40e9946d5/src/Http/Http/src/Features/RequestServicesFeature.cs#L35) class
- In Blazor Server the scope is the entire user session/channel

For middleware, the DI scope matters if you register a middleware class. By default a middleware class is Singleton unless it implements the `IMiddleware` interface. Such middleware is called [Factory-activated middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/extensibility?view=aspnetcore-7.0) and the default policy is to use scoped services

Comment: thank you, both of these links have been really helpful. I'll have to look more into middleware but if I understand correctly in a way the scope is bound to the http context, since the request is handed to the request pileline, which contains the middle, which creates the scope?